# java wsdl what wsdl elements are parse to java classes?

Tags: java, class, wsdl

I work with eclipse and I have a wsdl. I generated the java classes from this wsdl. But I don't have every wsdl element(request element)

The wsdl is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="urn:DefaultNameSpace" xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap"
 xmlns:impl="urn:DefaultNameSpace" xmlns:intf="urn:DefaultNameSpace" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
 xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <wsdl:types>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:DefaultNameSpace">
            <element name="LINEAS" type="xsd:string"/>
            <element name="TRAMOS" type="xsd:string"/>
            <element name="CODUSUARIO" type="xsd:string"/>
            <element name="NOMUSUARIO" type="xsd:string"/>
            <complexType name="LISTADO">
                <sequence>
                    <element name="RESULTADO" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <element name="MSG" type="xsd:string"/>
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
            <element name="LISTADODOCUMENTOSReturn" type="impl:LISTADO"/>
            <complexType name="Elemento1">
               <sequence>
                   <element name="LINEAS1" type="xsd:string"/>
                   <element name="TRAMOS1" type="xsd:string"/>
                   <element name="CODUSUARIO1" type="xsd:string"/>
                   <element name="NOMUSUARIO1" type="xsd:string"/>
               </sequence>
           </complexType>
           <element name="Elemento2" type="impl:Elemento1"/>
        </schema>

    </wsdl:types>
    <message name="LISTADODOCUMENTOSRequest">
        <part name="elementorequest"  element="impl:Elemento2"/>
    </message>
    <message name="LISTADODOCUMENTOSResponse">
        <part element="impl:LISTADODOCUMENTOSReturn" name="LISTADODOCUMENTOSReturn"/>
    </message>
    <portType name="DegradadoMercanciasNotes">
        <operation name="LISTADODOCUMENTOS">
            <input message="impl:LISTADODOCUMENTOSRequest" name="LISTADODOCUMENTOSRequest"/>
            <output message="impl:LISTADODOCUMENTOSResponse" name="LISTADODOCUMENTOSResponse"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="DominoSoapBinding" type="impl:DegradadoMercanciasNotes">
        <wsdlsoap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <operation name="LISTADODOCUMENTOS">
            <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
            <input name="LISTADODOCUMENTOSRequest">
                <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output name="LISTADODOCUMENTOSResponse">
                <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="DegradadoMercanciasNotesService">
        <port binding="impl:DominoSoapBinding" name="Domino">
            <wsdlsoap:address location="http://seguriteca.sir.renfe.es:80/u35/GDN/Seguriteca2017/Normativa.nsf/DegradadoMercancias?OpenWebService"/>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

From eclipse I generated the java classes. I would like to ask a question. What wsdl' elements are converted to java classes?. Because in my java classes I don't see neither

```
<message name="LISTADODOCUMENTOSRequest">
        <part name="elementorequest"  element="impl:Elemento2"/>
    </message>
```

nor

```
<element name="Elemento2" type="impl:Elemento1"/>
```

EDITED

My problem is in the WSDL'element

```
<message name="LISTADODOCUMENTOSRequest">
        <part element="impl:LINEAS" name="LINEAS" />
        <part element="impl:TRAMOS" name="TRAMOS" />
        <part element="impl:CODUSUARIO" name="CODUSUARIO" />
        <part element="impl:NOMUSUARIO" name="NOMUSUARIO" />
    </message>
```

When I try to generate the java classes an error happens in this element.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue a few months ago. I spent around a week or so trying to get it to work.

I tried **the majority of available IDEs**, and they **all** failed to generate all the valid classes with **NetBeans** being an exception; NetBeans worked unlike Eclipse and IntelliJ so what I reccomend to you is transfer **all** of your wsdl related code that's involved in **SOAP Request creation** or **generalised WSDL manipulation** over to NetBeans.

You will then be able to parse responses, and send requests as you'd like to be able to do in Eclipse, but in NetBeans; however, this will mean having it as a **standalone fat jar** containing all dependencies associated with the XML parsing etcetera included that you will be able to use **as a dependency in your Eclipse project**.

It was a very delaying process for me when manipulating National Rail's open source datafeeds but hopefully the following help you out much quicker!

**Generating Classes using JAX WS**:
 1. https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/client.html

**Creating a far jar in NetBeans**:
 1. Navigate to Files Explorer etc
 2. Locate build.xml & Right Click
 3. Hover over "Run Target"
 4. Hover over "Other Targets"
 5. Click "clean-and-fat-jar"

Doing so will give you nicely generated classes that you can send requests to with the following class (Note, I've not changed my default headers etc from my project, so you could reference them, and just replace them with what's required!)

**Please note**: I've reflected, for ease on my behalf, function names as a considerable amount of the request classes generated by **Jax WS** were named "create{bla bla}Request" etc.

```
public class SoapRequest {

    private final SOAPMessage request;
    private final String actionString;

    public SoapRequest(Action action, Document generatedRequestAsDoc) throws SOAPException {
        this.actionString = action.getActionString();
        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_2_PROTOCOL);
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
        SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

        // SOAP Envelope
        SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("ldb", "http://thalesgroup.com/RTTI/2017-10-01/ldb/");
        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("typ", "http://thalesgroup.com/RTTI/2013-11-28/Token/types");

        envelope.getHeader().
                addHeaderElement(new QName("http://thalesgroup.com/RTTI/2013-11-28/Token/types", "AccessToken")).
                addChildElement("typ:TokenValue").
                addTextNode(getTokenValue());
        soapMessage.getMimeHeaders().addHeader("Content-type", "application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action=" + createSoapAction(getActionString(), false));
        soapMessage.getMimeHeaders().addHeader("Accept-encoding", "gzip, x-gzip, deflate, x-bzip2");

        soapMessage.getMimeHeaders().addHeader("SOAPAction", "http://thalesgroup.com/RTTI/2017-10-01/ldb/ " + createSoapAction(getActionString(), true));

        soapMessage.getSOAPBody().addDocument(generatedRequestAsDoc); //adding the generated request by jax client to the body

        soapMessage.saveChanges();
        this.request = soapMessage;
    }

    private static String createSoapAction(String action, boolean appendRequest) {
        return action + (appendRequest ? "Request" : "");
    }

    private static Document getMarshalledDocument(JAXBElement<?> element, JAXBContext jaxbContext) {
        Document document = getEmptyDoc();
        try {
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(element, document);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            Logger.getLogger(IdealTrains.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
            document = null;
        }
        return document;
    }

    @Nullable
    public static Document generateDoc(JAXBElement<?> element) {
        Class elementClass = element.getDeclaredType();
        Document generatedDoc = null;
        try {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(elementClass);
            generatedDoc = getMarshalledDocument(element, jaxbContext);
            if (generatedDoc == null) {
                System.out.println("Could not marshall, terminating...");
                return null;
            }
            return generatedDoc;
        } catch (JAXBException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SoapRequest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        return generatedDoc;
    }

    @Nullable
    public SoapResponse sendRequestForResponse() {
        try {
            // Create SOAP Connection
            SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
            SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

            // Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server
            SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(getRequest(), IdealTrains.STAFF_WEBSERVICE_ENDPOINT);
            soapConnection.close();
            return new SoapResponse(soapResponse);
        } catch (UnsupportedOperationException | SOAPException e) {
            System.err.println("\nError occurred while sending SOAP Request to Server!\nMake sure you have the correct endpoint URL and SOAPAction!\n");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static Document getEmptyDoc() {
        Document document = null;
        try {
            document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(IdealTrains.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return document;
    }

    private static String getTokenValue() {
        return IdealTrains.AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN;
    }

    private SOAPMessage getRequest() {
        return this.request;
    }

    public String getActionString() {
        return actionString;
    }

    public String getResponseString() {
        return getActionString() + "Response";
    }
}

public class Action {

    private final Object objectFactory;
    private final String response;
    private String actionString;
    private Service.ServiceType serviceType;

    public Action(Object objectFactory, String getString, Service.ServiceType serviceType) {
        this.actionString = getString;
        this.objectFactory = objectFactory;
        this.response = getString + "Response";
        this.serviceType = serviceType;
    }

    public JAXBElement<?> doParams(Object genericType) {
        String functionNameInFacClass = "create" + getActionString() + "Request";
        Method func = null;
        Class gTypeClass = genericType.getClass();
        Object invokedResponse = null;
        try {
            func = getObjectFactory().getClass().getMethod(functionNameInFacClass, gTypeClass);
            invokedResponse = func.invoke(getObjectFactory(), genericType); //Invoke createACTIONRequest in suitable object factory
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        JAXBElement<?> element = (JAXBElement<?>) invokedResponse;
        return element;
    }

    public Object getObjectFactory() {
        return objectFactory;
    }

    public String getActionString() {
        return actionString;
    }

    public String getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public Service.ServiceType getServiceType() {
        return this.serviceType;
    }

    public void setServiceType(Service.ServiceType serviceType) {
        this.serviceType = serviceType;
    }

    public void setAction(String actionString) {
        this.actionString = actionString;
    }
}
```